# Reading Java command line arguments on Unix

Tags: java

I am trying to read a folder name from command line for a Java application on Unix.

I have a ksh script (test.ksh) and it has the line:

```
java SomApp $*
```

I am trying to execute this as below:

```
test.ksh ../folder
```

But this fails; I mean my Java application says there is nothing under "../folder" though there are some files.

How to read such relative paths on Unix?

Comment: Can you post the actual error?  Also posting the line of code you are using to read the folder name would probably be a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

--snip--

If you want each filename under your folder as an argument to your command, try something like

```
java SomeApp `ls ../folder`
```

...which will execute the ls command against ../folder and substitute the output (the list of files under ../folder).

Comment: What shell requires single quotes? Isn't globbing with ../folder/* more customary?

Comment: Suggested the single quotes as I as I misunderstood one of the askers comments - on re-read agree, removed from answer. As for what is customary, I dunno - my answer was the first thing that popped into my head but ../folder/* should work but includes relative path info in the output, which might be what the asker wants, can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program to list the files in a directory specified on the command line.

```
public static void main(String... argv) {
  File[] list = new File(argv[0]).listFiles();
  for (File f : list) {
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key question is "Does the Java application expect a directory name or a list of file names?"

If the application expects a directory name, you appear to have given it a directory name.  Unless your shell script does something unexpected such as change working directory (`cd`), the problem is most likely in the application.

If the application expects a list of file names, then you should pass it file names and not a directory name.  That might be just:

```
./test.ksh ../folder/*
```

Or you might need to be more selective if the folder also contains sub-folders and the application will be upset by folder names instead of file names.